# How can I move a user account to another domain in the forest, whilst preserving permissions?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain, user-management

I've got user John Doe in the Server 2003 parent domain 'foo', which has a child domain 'bar'. Both domains are at a functional level of Server 2000.

I'd like to move the user to the 'bar' domain, while preserving their access to network resources. I can easily put them into the appropriate groups within the new domain, but some of our file share permissions are per-user. The user also has an Exchange 2003 account.

Is is possible to move the user and retain all their permissions and mailbox? If so, what tools are available to me that could help me accomplish that?

Note: I'm aware that Server 2003 is well beyond end-of-life and unsafe to use. Not my call, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Active Directory Migration Tools. when you use these tools to migrate User accounts the original Security Identifier (SID) is kept. So when a user tries to access resources the new SID or the original SID can be used. This feature is called SID history and is an optional option of the Active Directory Migration tools. There is a link below that will take you to a ADMT guide:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(v=ws.10).aspx

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. ADMT is the first thing comes to my mind.